# c# webbrowser authorization header

Tags: c#, com, webbrowser-control

I need to add authorization header in webBrowser

```
 private void webBrowser_Navigating(object sender, WebBrowserNavigatingEventArgs e)
    {
        string headers = "Authorization: Bearer " + AuthorizationState.Token + (char)10 + (char)13;
        webBrowser.Navigate(e.Url, null, null, headers);
    }
```

I tried to use this solution, but always receive an error: 
"An exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component."

How can I add authorization header for every request in WebBrowser control? What is wrong with my code?

I have authorization token in application and I need to use it in WebBrowser request.

Thanks

Comment: I bet it works outside of the `_Navigating` event.  Your `.Navigate` fires `_Navigating` within `_Navigating` so you are going to loop around in `_Navigating` until something breaks.

Comment: Thanks, but I turn off event before the call in real code. Still have a question, how to add header per every request in webBrowser

Comment: I can add a header during the navigating event. I wonder if your AuthorizationState.Token  has some characters that COM call doesn't like. Does it contain only ASCII or are there unicode characters in there?